# How to change UITextField Font size within an Alert

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to make my font size larger in the textField that is currently placed within an alert:

```
func showAlert() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    // Add text field
    ac.addTextField(configurationHandler: { textField in
        
        
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        textField.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
   
        textField.minimumFontSize = 100
        
    })
```

Comment: You don't. You create your own custom class alert. Else, it would be using private API that could break at any iOS release and might be a also cause rejection from Apple at any submission.

Comment: @Larme would the answer to this question cause rejection from Apple? Or is that a possible solution?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you wanted to change the text, not the textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `textField.minimumFontSize = 100` line to `textField.font = UIFont(name: "*whateverFontNameYouAreUsing*", size: 30)`. Let me know if this worked. Thanks.

[check this code and font size in simulator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWPY8.jpg)

Comment: This worked! But will this cause rejection from Apple at submission? Like @Larme said?

Comment: @Jordan I don't think so it will cause any issue because we are just changing font size just like we do for other elements like label, button etc. Thanks.